# Converting Python into Java and facing some issues

Tags: java, python, hashmap

I'm converting the following Python Code into Java code as follows:

```
import random
howMany = random.randint(0,1000)
stats = {}
for i in range(howMany):
value = random.randint(0,500)
stats.setdefault(value,0)
stats[value]+=1
for item in stats:
if stats[item] > 1:
    print item
```

Here is the Java code I have written so far :

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

public class PythonToJava 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Random rm = new Random();
        int i = rm.nextInt(1000);
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> stats = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        System.out.println("Random Number Generated is: " + i);
        for (int j = 0; j<i; j++)
        {
            int value = rm.nextInt(500);
            System.out.println("The value of VALUE is " + value);
            DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer> defaultvalue = new DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer>();
            defaultvalue.put(value,0);
        }
    }
}

public class DefaultingMap<Integer, Integer> implements Map<Integer, Integer>
{
    private final Map<Integer, Integer> map;
    private final Integer defaultValue;
    public DefaultingMap(Map<Integer, Integer> map, Integer defaultValue)
    {
        this.map = map;
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    @Override public Integer get(Object key)
    {
        Integer ret = map.get(key);
        if (ret == null)
        {
            ret = defaultValue;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    @Override public int size()
    {
        return map.size();
    }
    // etc
}
```

But getting error at the following line:

Java Code:

`DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer> defaultvalue = new DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer>();`
Error is : The constructor DefaultingMap() is undefined

and at `public class DefaultingMap<Integer, Integer> implements Map<Integer, Integer>`

```
Error is : Multiple markers at this line
    - The type DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer> must implement the inherited abstract method 
     Map<Integer,Integer>.remove(Object)
    - The type parameter Integer is hiding the type Integer
    - The type DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer> must implement the inherited abstract method 
     Map<Integer,Integer>.put(Integer, Integer)
    - The type DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer> must implement the inherited abstract method 
     Map<Integer,Integer>.keySet()
    - The type DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer> must implement the inherited abstract method 
     Map<Integer,Integer>.values()
    - The type DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer> must implement the inherited abstract method 
     Map<Integer,Integer>.containsKey(Object)
    - The type parameter Integer is hiding the type Integer
    - The type DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer> must implement the inherited abstract method 
     Map<Integer,Integer>.containsValue(Object)
    - Duplicate type parameter Integer
    - The type DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer> must implement the inherited abstract method 
     Map<Integer,Integer>.entrySet()
    - The type DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer> must implement the inherited abstract method 
     Map<Integer,Integer>.putAll(Map<? extends Integer,? extends Integer>)
    - The type DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer> must implement the inherited abstract method 
     Map<Integer,Integer>.isEmpty()
    - The type DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer> must implement the inherited abstract method 
     Map<Integer,Integer>.clear()
```

Can anyone explain why?

Basically I'm trying to set a default value somehow just like setdefault thing works in python. I would appreciate if someone can help me here.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: DefaultingMap does not appear to be a part of the standard JDK. You may need to add additional libraries or simply use another class.

Comment: Added the error. I'm using Eclipse IDE. What could be the alternative then? @StevenLiao

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart its add the bottom of the code block

Comment: Is DefaultingMap in the same file as PythonToJava? You cannot define two public classes in the same file.

Comment: @BevynQ  Yes, can I just remove the public keyword from DefaultingMap class? Although it didn't work. What could be an alternative?

Comment: Yes or put it in a different file.

Comment: @AaK yes u can remove, or alternatively, you can put the DefaultingMap  as separate file.

Comment: @ay89 As I mentioned, removing public keyword didn't work can you explain why? I'm planning to keep it in same file

Comment: Also, I'm wondering, if I put it in a separate `.java` file, what could be the `classname.java`

Comment: you dont have default counstructor, either provide it, or pass the required parameters.

Comment: @ay89 How can I provide default constructor in terms of HashMap class? Could you write it down?

Comment: see the ans from @asif.

Comment: @Aak default constructor is a constructor without parameters, it gets called that because it is provided automatically if you do not provide any constructors. If you do define a constructor then the default constructor is not provided if you do not define it.

Comment: @BevynQ Thank you. I mentioned `public DefaultingMap()
{
  // do your things
}` as suggested below but the second error still persists. What could be the reason?

Comment: Also note that Python's `randint(0,1000)` equates to Java `nextInt(1001)`, and same with the 500. Java's range is exclusive, Pythons is inclusive.

Comment: @Aak you get noting given to you in Java, A class that implements an interface must implement all the methods defined or extend a class that does.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker How can I resolve range conflict. Even I was wondering about that but didn't find any method in Random() class of java.

Comment: You found the right code...`nextInt()`. It just interprets the range argument differently. You have to add 1. What "conflict"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I see is You have parameterized constructor in `DefaultingMap` and default constructor is missing. Kindly Add default constructor

```
public DefaultingMap()
{
  // do your things
}
```

Otherwise change this call

```
DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer> defaultvalue = new DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer>();
defaultvalue.put(value,0);
```

to this

```
DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer> defaultvalue = new DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer>(value,0);
```

**UPDATED**
It is clear that you need to override all the methods from the MAP you have just overriden few. Kindly over-ride all the methods. Then this will resolve your issue
Following methods to over-ride

```
remove
put
keySet
values
containsKey
containsValue
entrySet
putAll
isEmpty
```

Refer [Method Summary Section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to see the methods to override

**SUGGESTION** 
If you do not wish to over-ride all the methods from *MAP* (as its really a pain) then rather than `implements MAP` you can have `extends HashMap`. With this you just have to over-ride the methods which you would like to. As in your case *get* and *size*

Comment: Mentioning `public DefaultingMap()
{
  // do your things
}` did work but the second error still persists which is "Multiple Markers at this line.

Comment: Can you tell us what is the other errors? Firstly, separate both the `class` into different files (As only one public class is permitted per file)

Comment: It is clear that you need to override all the methods from the `MAP` you have just overriden few. Kindly over-ride all the methods. Then this will resolve your issue

Comment: Not sure which methods I need to override again. Could you please mention it here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would rather extend `HashMap` here and after doing that also nothing changed. What could be the reason? Here is what I changed:

`class DefaultingMap<Integer, Integer> extends HashMap<Integer, Integer>`

Comment: Your welcome :) Its just that you need to implement all the methods of interface otherwise the compiler will keep on shouting. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29639/discussion-between-aak-and-asifsid88)

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't do it as I'm in office and the chat room is blocked :(

Answer (score 0):

i modified

```
DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer> defaultvalue = new DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer>();
```

to

```
DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer> defaultvalue = new DefaultingMap<Integer,Integer>(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(),0);
```

Also

```
public class DefaultingMap<Integer, Integer> implements Map<Integer, Integer>
{
    private final Map<Integer, Integer> map;
    private final Integer defaultValue;

    public DefaultingMap(Map<Integer, Integer> map, Integer defaultValue)
    {
        this.map = map;
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    @Override public Integer get(Object key)
    {
        Integer ret = map.get(key);
        if (ret == null)
        {
            ret = defaultValue;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

became

```
class DefaultingMap<K, V> implements Map<K,V>{ //remove public and use proper generic parameters

   private final Map<K, V> map; // is now generic
   private final V defaultValue; // must be of type V

   public DefaultingMap(Map<K, V> map, V defaultValue) throws IllegalArgumentException
   {
   /* because we have defined this constructor DefaultingMap() will need to be 
      defined if we need/want it. */
       if (map == null){
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("provided map cannot be null");
       }
       this.map = map;
       this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
   }

   public V get(Object key){

       V ret = map.get(key);
       if (ret == null){
           ret = defaultValue;
       }
       return ret;
   }
```

You need to implement all the methods in the Map interface do them this way if you are unsure

```
   @Override
   public V put(K key, V value) {
       return map.put(key,value); // delegate to map
   }
```

that worked for me.

Comment: Hi @BevynQ , Thanks for your answer. Could you please update your code for extending a class HashMap instead? I'm preferring to extend a class instead of overriding all the methods of Interface.